# Categorizing inputs in QListView

Tags: qt, listview

I have a few things going on in my GUI. What I wanted was to be able to push information in a QListView. 
The way I wanted was that it be categorized. 
Say,

> ---Event A---
>
> aspect_a
>
> aspect_b
>
> ---Event B---
>
> aspect_c
>
> aspect_d
>
> ...
>
> --- ... and so on in QListView.

aspects may come in any order. I would like to put them in event categorized way.

I couldn't really find anything inbuilt which could handle such a thing. Is there something that does this in QT ?

If not how do I make it do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [QTreeView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html), but it will be a little more complicated than a QListView as you'll have to create a  [QAbstractItemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QAbstractItemModel.html) for your data. A simple tutorial can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html)